# .net core: Is Assert supported with C# on .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Do we have  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert() support in .net core with C#? Is there a alternative for this based on .net core?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [check the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netcore-1.0#System_Diagnostics_Debug_Assert_System_Boolean_), from there you can see both .NET Core 1.0 and newer and NetStandard 1.0 and newer both support `Debug.Assert(bool)`.

If it is not working for you, you might need to include the NuGet package [`System.Diagnostics.Debug`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Debug/) in your project for it to show up.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am new to .net core and has just imported "Using System.Diagnostics.Debug" and was calling Assert() directly. I changed it to " Using System.Diagnostics;" and then make calls using "Debug.Assert()"